# How to Customize a Chatter in Salesforce?

Tags: apex

Is it possible same like standard Chatter? If yes How?

Display Standard Chatter on Viusalforce page using apex? is it possible or not

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show a chatter component in VF page, you can use the following code

```
<apex:page >
  <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm

Entity ID of the record for which to display the feed; for example, Contact.Id

You could also do SOQL query the feeds and use apex:repeat to display the records in whichever way you want to

Check out some of the code recipes http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes